# insert local javasscript into iframe html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, iframe

I am trying to put some HTML code into iframe to present data. Everythink works fine, but when I want to put any java script in an iframe there is no result. It seems that iframe cannot see any local javascript.

Here is a code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src="testJSON.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
     <iframe id="frame"></iframe>
    <p id="demo"></p>
        <script src="names.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $("#frame").attr(
            "src", "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + 
            "<html><head>"+
            "<script src='jquery.min.js'><"+"/script>"+
            "<script src='testJSON.js'><"+"/script></head>"+ 
            "<body><p id='demo'></p>"+
            "<script src='name.js'><"+"/script>"+  
            "<h1>Test</h1>"+
            "</body></html>"
        );
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

testJSON.js:

```
var dane = '{ "names" : [' +
'{ "firstName":"Ana" , "lastName":"Doe" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Bill" , "lastName":"Smith" },' +
'{ "firstName":"Dory" , "lastName":"Jones" } ]}';
```

names.js:

```
var nameID =function() {
    return 2;
};

obj = JSON.parse(dane);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.names[nameID()].firstName + " " + obj.names[nameID()].lastName;
```

Has anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Is this page hosted locally, or is at a server, local or web server?

Comment: As a side note, if you don't have to support IE, you should use the [srcdoc attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume DataURIs cannot contain external scripts for security reasons but I cannot find the duplicate SO post that confirms this. Anyway, document.write the html and script into the frame. That works

```
$("#frame")[0].document.contentDocument.write(
        "<html><head>"+
        "<script src='jquery.min.js'><\/script>"+
        "<script src='testJSON.js'><\/script></head>"+ 
        "<body><p id='demo'></p>"+
        "<script src='name.js'><\/script>"+  
        "<h1>Test</h1>"+
        "</body></html>"
    );
$("#frame")[0].contentDocument.close();
```

you may need to fully qualify the URLs of the external files

Comment: Many thanks. I've changed $("#frame").attr( into:$("#frame")[0].contentDocument.write and it works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a race problem: youre trying to access the json, before the iframe is loaded, therefore, dane will be undefined. Use listeners or kinda callback.

Callback:

```
//in your page:
function parse(json){
//do sth with json
}
//in the iframe:
parse("{}");
```

Listeners:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].onload=function(){
//you parsing js
};
```